# how to respond to revmob sdk uialertview delegate?

Tags: ios, popup, uialertview, banner-ads, revmob

Im trying to implement revmob sdk,
it works fine but their documentation dont have much detail and support not responding.
(http://sdk.revmob.com/sdks/ios/docs/index.html)

is there a way to use the delegate to know the status of the alertbox ?

this is what I currently use to call:

```
[BCFAds showPopupWithAppID:@"appId" withDelegate:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after starting to ask the question I found the answer,
so incase someone else have this problem here is the solution.

1. to your .h file add a delegate called BCFAdsDelegate.
2. add #import "BCFAds.h"
3. in the .m file where you call the sdk add
   `[BCFAds showPopupWithAppID:@"appId" withDelegate:self];`
4. use the method you want:

`- (void)popupDidDismissActive;`
// Called when user is back to the app

`- (void)popupDidReceive;`
// Called when a popup is available

`- (void)popupDidFail;`
// Called when a popup is not available

`- (void)popupDidBecomeActive;`
// Called when popup is displayed

`- (void)popupDidDismissActive;`
// Called when user is back to the app

`- (void)userWillLeaveApplication;`
// Called when user clicked and is about to leave the application